# LINQ: A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause and other errors

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
CASE  
WHEN wt.pmtlr_oi IS NULL OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mc.SCHEDENTRY WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE wt_oi = wt.wtskoi AND shedref_oi NOT IN (SELECT shdoi FROM mc.SCHDULE WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE aenm LIKE '%Breakin%')) = 0   AND wt.pmtlr_oi IS NULL     
THEN 'Break-In' 
ELSE 'Planned' 
END AS schedule
```

which I have translated into:

```
Schedule = wt.pmtlr_oi == null || (from sch in SCHEDENTRies where wt_oi == wt.wtskoi && shedref_oi !(from sc in SCHDULEs
    where sc.Aenm.Contains("Breakin") select sc.Shdoi)).Count() == 0 && wt.pmtlr_oi == null ? "Break-In" : "Planned"}
```

Here's how it looks in the select statement:

```
select new {Schedule = wt.pmtlr_oi == null || (from sch in SCHEDENTRies where wt_oi == wt.wtskoi && shedref_oi !(from sc in SCHDULEs
    where sc.Aenm.Contains("Breakin") select sc.Shdoi)).Count() == 0 && wt.pmtlr_oi == null ? "Break-In" : "Planned"});
```

However when I try and run it there are some problems which I do not know how to fix.  The first one is that the compiler doesn't appear to like the NOT IN found here:

```
&& shedref_oi !(from sc in SCHDULEs
```

I get a "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause" error.

The compiler also doesn't like this:

```
select sc.Shdoi)).Count() == 0
```

On the outer parenthesis I get a "Syntax error ',' expected" error and on the period I get a "Statement expected" error message.

I would appreciate some help in troubleshooting this.

EDIT:

OK, After the comments I have corrected the LINQ statement to look like this:

```
select new {Schedule = wt.pmtlr_oi == null || (from sch in SCHEDENTRies where wt_oi == wt.wtskoi && !(from sc in SCHDULEs
    where sc.Aenm.Contains("Breakin") select sc.Shdoi).Contains(shedref_oi)).Count() == 0 && wt.pmtlr_oi == null ? "Break-In" : "Planned"});
```

and the compiler likes it.  However, it still doesn't like the .Count(). I get a "Statement expected" error.  Am I incorrect in using .Count() for the sql SELECT COUNT(*)?

Comment: `&& shedref_oi !(from sc in SCHDULEs`: you have a syntax error here... the `!` operator is unary, so `x ! y` means nothing.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I'm confused about this.  Why does it mean nothing here yet means NOT IN on Mark Russo's example found here:  http://introducinglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx.  I thought the ! operator was the equivalent of a sql NOT IN

Comment: You want `!(from sc in SCHDULEs where sc.Aenm.Contains("Breakin") select sc.Shdoi).Contains(shedref_oi)` - the `!` is applied to the result of `Contains`

Comment: @Rawling That got rid of the two errors at the Count() method but the compiler still doesn't like the ! operator. However, I now see the relationship between the ! operator and Contains() on Mark Russo's blog. I didn't see that they worked together.  Thank you for that.

Comment: If I put the ! operator in front of where sc.Aenm.Contains("Breakin") select sc.Shdoi).Contains(shedref_oi) instead of in fromt of the parenthesis the compiler will accept it.  However, wouldn't this be different from the sql statement?

Comment: Replace the Count == 0 with !Any(). Any short circuits (or at the database level is translated into Exists).